# Turn off equation numbers when using 'preview' package

Tags: equations, preview

I am trying to export all of the equations from my document.

I have added

```
\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
```

then compiled, and then from a command line run:

```
pdfcrop output.pdf
gs -sDEVICE=png16m -dTextAlphaBits=4 -r300 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dSAFER -q -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=Equation_%d.png output-crop.pdf -dBATCH
```

but the result I get is a very long line with the equation as well as the equation number. Is there a way to turn off equation numbers only when running with this package (i.e. without changing every `{equation}` to `{equation*}`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the `equation` environment to sandwich the math expression with `\preview$\displaystyle` and `$\endpreview`.

### Method 1

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewBorder=3pt\relax

\renewenvironment{equation}
{\preview$\displaystyle}
{$\endpreview}

\begin{document}

This is a theorem in calculus.
\begin{equation}
F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Do you know it?
\begin{equation}
E\ne mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

### Method 2

```
\documentclass[preview,border=3pt,varwidth,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\renewenvironment{equation}
{\preview$\displaystyle}
{$\endpreview}

\begin{document}

This is a theorem in calculus.
\begin{equation}
F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Do you know it?
\begin{equation}
E\ne mc^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

### PDF to PNG conversion

To convert all PDF pages to PNG images, use ImageMagick's command as follows.

```
convert -compose copy -bordercolor magenta -border 1x1 -density <value> -alpha <option> input.pdf output%02d.png
```

Remark:

- `value` is an interger. Use bigger/smaller value to enlarge/shrink the image.
- `option` can be one of 3 options: `on` (enable transparency) , `off` (disable transparency, but it produces bad output) , `remove` (remove transparency with good output).
- `%02d` means the output filename will be followed by 2 digit numbers. For example: `output01.png`, `output02.png`, ... `output69.png`.

Comment: Important notes: don't use `convert` to convert PDF to EPS. Instead, use `pdftops`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference between using Image Magick and that gs command that I has posted?

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to do

```
\makeatletter
\let\@eqnswtrue\@eqnswfalse
\makeatother
```

The [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) package provides automatic conversion with the included `png` option or the fully configurable [`convert`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf#page=15) options.

### Code (borrowed from [PGFTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19356/pgftricks)’ [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134145/16595))

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}    % or …
%\documentclass{article}                % … and …
%\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview} % … instead
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\@eqnswtrue\@eqnswfalse
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a theorem in calculus.
\begin{equation}
F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)\, \textrm{d}x
\end{equation}

Do you know it?
\begin{equation}
E\ne mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: From what I just read, \makeatletter is needed because @ is typically not allowed outside of a package, and @ is usually needed to override functionality inside of a package. Is it not necessary to know which package eqnswtrue/false come from? Googling for those didn't turn up any hits - what do they stand for? eqn = equation obviously, but what about "swtrue"?

Comment: @DavidDoria For `\makeatletter` see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351) I assume EqNsW stands for Equation Number Switch. I can’t a documentation on that switch but it is used in the source of `amsmath` to switch tags on and off.